# Problem when dualbooting ubuntu 21.04 and windows 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 21.04

When installing ubuntu i got the **`grub-install /dev/sda failed`** error. I used the boot repair tool and thought everything was fine until i unpluged the usb and restarted the pc. No matter what disk i chose to boot in, i got the grub (grub>). Now i am stuck with the usb installer

Comment: UEFI or BIOS install? MBR or gpt partitioned drive? Best just to post link to summary report from Boot-Repair, so we all can see details of your boot configuration.

Answer (score 0):

That is a common Grub error that could occur with any Linux OS like Ubuntu or Debian. Solution:

Find the partition in which your Linux partition is stored.

`grub> ls`
This will show us all existing partitions.
via `grub> ls (hdX, Y)` you can describe the partitions you have (example - `grub> ls (hd0, gpt1)` ).

Then, After knowing the partition where is your Linux stored, you need to set your root and prefix settings:

```
grub> set root=(hdX, Y)
grub> set prefix=(hdX, Y)/boot/grub
```

(where hdX and Y is your Linux partition)

After that, install the normal module:

```
grub> insmod normal
```

and run it

```
grub> normal
```

Now you should successfully boot into your Linux system but you need to update your GRUB. In the terminal:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now everything should be OK, Enjoy Ubuntu 21.04 :)

Best Regards, ykostov